# How can I use a query written in TSQL in sql server as data source for my dataGridView?

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I need a calculated column and to do achieve this I plan on using a query in TSQL from sql server 2014 the problem is I don't know how to use that query as data source for my dataGridView in vb.net. I'm using visual studio 2015. Can someone help point me in the right direction? I just need to display the results of my query in dataGridView. The calculated column will need data from multiple tables and the only way I can create the column is by using a TSQL query in SQL Server.

Comment: Query is not a data source. But we query on datasource

Comment: Make your tsql query as stored procedure and call it from vb.net

Comment: Is there a way for me to display in dataGridView the results of my query?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you give an example as to how I can use and connect the stored procedure im vb.net?

Comment: Since it is explained so many websites and blogs I am giving reference link in my answer. Please check it out. @Euphemia

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind sql query to `DataGridView.DataSource`.
But you can with result of your query, for example you can get result as `DataTable`

```vb
Public Function GetData() As DataTable
    Dim yourQuery As String = "...."

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(yourConnectionString)
        Using command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            ' Add parameters if you need
            'command.Parameters.AddRange(arrayOfSqlParameters)

            connection.Open()

            Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                Dim data As New DataTable()
                adapter.Fill(data)
                Return data
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Then use result as DataSource

```
Dim data As DataTable = GetData()
myDataGridView.DataSource = data
```

If you don't like `DataTable` you can load data to the list of your classes which represent data and use it as datasource

```
Dim data As List<Customer> = GetCustomerData()
myDataGridView.DataSource = data
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a stored procedure for your T-SQL code. And call the same stored procedure from VB.Net

Here is a good example explained for the same.

[Using SQL Stored Procedures with VB.NET](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/using-sql-stored-procedures-with-vb.net.htm)

Comment: I actually saw that article a while ago but I still don't understand how I can connect or display it to dataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of GetData() above. This one uses a DataReader instead which requires less overhead. There's some extra bells and whistles in there which aren't really needed - you really only need `rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()`

```
Function GetDataTable(ByVal SQL As String, Optional ByVal ConnectString As String = "", Optional ByVal SingleRow As Boolean = False) As DataTable ' returns read only Datatable
    Try
        If ConnectString.Length = 0 Then ConnectString = g.OISConnectString()
        Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectString)
            Dim rdr As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, con)
            If SingleRow Then
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow Or CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Else
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            End If
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(rdr)
            rdr.Close()
            Return dt
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, , "GetDataTable")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```